# how to choose a particular variant of the \upgamma glyph when using upgreek package

Tags: fonts, symbols

The `upgreek` package uses upright Greek characters from either the PostScript Symbol font or Euler Roman ([The Comprehensive Latex Symbol List](http://zelmanov.ptep-online.com/ctan/symbols-a4.pdf) page 50)
I wanted to type the `\upgamma` in the PostScript Symbol font, but it types in Euler form. How can I set the package to use the to Postscript mode?

Comment: I need to say I have to write in equation mode as well.

Comment: By the way, there's a newer list of symbols, look on CTAN please! And please provide a compilable document -- at the moment, I don't your question.

Answer (score 2):

To get the Adobe symbol version rather than the Euler version of the glyphs, load the [upgreek](http://ctan.org/pkg/upgreek) package with either the option `Symbol` or the option `Symbolsmallscale`; the latter option scales the glyphs down by about 10 percent.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[Symbol]{upgreek}
\begin{document}
$\upgamma$
\end{document}
```

Comment: And is there any similar option for txfonts/pxfonts packages?

Comment: @Reza - The user guides of the [txfonts](http://ctan.org/pkg/txfonts) and [pxfonts](http://ctan.org/pkg/pxfonts) packages make no mention of such an option. By the way, these packages have not been updated in more than a decade. You should really consider using the following successor packages: `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` have succeeded `txfonts`, and `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` have succeeded `pxfonts`.